# How to stop a page from auto-updating (Meteor)?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor app. that allow the user to dynamically add items to a list. The adding of the items is done directly in the DOM first, then a document, relating to this new item, will be inserted into MongoDB once the user has finished adding the item. 
How do I prevent the page from automatically pulling in new list items (that might have been added by some other user, for example) whilst the current user is adding their new list item(s)? Is there a way for the application to stop listening for any new documents added to MongoDB until the application starts telling it to start again (note that the auto-updating should only be prevented for a designated area of the page, i.e. for a particular Meteor template)?

Comment: Sounds very strange. Could you give some example why you would like to stop reactivity? What's your use case? Maybe there is some other solution to get effect you want...

Comment: Because (and bare in mind my knowledge of Meteor is limited) in my mind, if I am adding an item to a list and this item is being edited, I don't want other items to suddenly appear and shift down/up where the user's eye-line is. Essentially, I don't wan re-activity for the whole list whilst the user is looking/editing the it, but there might be other sections of the page where re-activity needs to remain, e.g. a count of new list items that have been added to the list by other user whilst the current user has been looking at the list.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** I'm not sure this will work or not,I'm just guessing, I haven't tried this code

For cursors there is an option field called `reactive` you can play with it if you don't want to updates from that cursor

```
Posts.find({},{reactive : false});
```

Documentation http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find

Try changing the `reactive` property using session variable,

while you're adding block to div set session variable as `false` so it will not listen for changes,after completio of adding block to DOM set it back to `true`